# playing a sound in iOS smoothly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio

I have an object moving around the screen and once it reaches the edges it it changes direction and plays a sound this all works fine except that when it plays the sound I freezes for about half a second is there any way of making this run smoothly with the sound and object movement?

```
-(void)viewDidLoader
{
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ballbounce" ofType:@"mp3"];
ballbounce = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] error: NULL];
[ballbounce prepareToPlay];
}

-(void) ballcollition 
{
[self ballplaysound]
enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);

    if (enemy.center.x > 328 || enemy.center.x < 0)

    {
        pos.x = -pos.x;



    }
}
-(void)ballplaysound
{
if (enemy.center.x > 328 || enemy.center.x < 0 ||enemy.center.y < 0||enemy.center.y < 300)
[ballbounce play];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the System Sound for sound that plays smoothly.

Original NON-ARC answer:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

- (IBAction)soundButton:(id)sender {

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"wav"];

SystemSoundID soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

[soundPath release];

}
```

Updated for ARC, and turned into a utility function:

```
- (void)soundPlay:(NSString*)waveName {
    // wavName = @"alert" without any file extension (not alert.wav)

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:waveName ofType: @"wav"];

    SystemSoundID soundID;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);


}
```

Comment: Hey this worked after alot of tweaking but definitely a lot less over heads

Comment: I updated it for ARC.  Note that there is something weird going on with quotes turning into some other non-valid-in-LLFM character that was confusing, if you copy paste the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can gain sound "smoothness" with `AVPlayer` by simply converting your `mp3` to `caf` format as explained [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=335683).

Answer (score 0):

1) Create AVAudioPLayer and cache it in your apps initialization code and never call it again
also call prepare as well.

2) so the method you included should only have to call play;

3)  If you still get a skip use

```
[ballbounce performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(play) withObject:nil];
```

Since you didnt include all the code and you are clearly doing drawing - putting the play method
on the queue could let the drawing code finish without interruption.

Doing this correctly might fix you.  Using AudioSystemSound is much lower overhead but you should follow the same principles of preparing any often used sounds in your app initialization and not spawning them at the exact time you need them to avoid performance issues.

Comment: hey @stackmoster when you talk about putting into a queue how would i do this as i have never done anything like that before?

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread posts the method to the queue by itself, this might get the sound IO out of the way of the graphics drawing.

Comment: Hi i have edited the code to what i think is you'r proposed solution but it is still lagging when playing the sound